# SQL Server query designer on C# application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssms

I have been given the tasking of providing a desktop solution which allows a user to simply and safely create bespoke reporting queries where their knowledge of the database is limited.

Immediately what came to mind is the SQL server query designer in SSMS.  I have searched the internet with no success of whether this can be integrated into a C# Windows Forms application.  Has anyone had any success of invoking this functionality in C#?

Comment: OK, thanks, it would need to understand the complexities of the joins etc like SSMS. thanks for your comment

Comment: Do you have a `DBA` on Staff..? if so work with them to create the necessary database query's never give users direct access to your tables they can reap havoc

Answer (score 2):

I used to work with Korzh's EasyQuery component in ASP.NET MVC, but they have the WinForms edition too.

It seems like exactly what you need - the database structure is hidden, end user operates with visual "conditions" and "columns", you get an SQL query as a result.

Here is the link: http://devtools.korzh.com/easyquery/